# How to upload (Best way to upload) whole OctoberCMS project from localhost to live server

Tags: octobercms

I am new to **OctoberCMS** and currently i am developing one project in the same **CMS** in my **local server** . . say it has a url something like **http://localhost/october_cms/**

Now my question is, how to upload [*best way to upload*] my whole new project to live server with database with the new url itself .. something like **http://www.example.com/** or something like **http://www.subdomain.example.com/** or **http://www.example.com/octobercms** anyway ?

I want the database urls should be changed as well without any hurdle or any issues after i upload on live server.

Any idea or any plugin **OctoberCMS** provides to deal with this thing ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't going to be a best way I'm afraid - these things come down to developer choice in terms of what kind of server to run it on.

If you're not sure about what stack to run, then personally I would suggest setting up a Ubuntu (14.04) install on a VPS - it's a linux OS that is really widely used so Googling problems will always come up with a result. You can use a cloud hosting provider like [Linode.com](https://www.linode.com) or [DigitalOcean.com](https://www.digitalocean.com) to spin up a server in no time. DigitalOcean in particular I really like their guides to setting up servers - very comprehensive.

Once you've got a server up and running and you can login via SSH or FTP, you can copy over your local project multiple ways. You could for example setup a fresh install following the October CMS documentation and then copy your project over the top via FTP - this is probably the most simple way as if you have good FTP software then it's just like copying files locally. Another option would be to use version control software like git and a service to manage this like [GitHub](https://github.com), so you can quickly copy your project and also manage it using version control.

I'm not sure what you mean by database urls? What database have you got running locally? In any case, this should be an easy part of the process - once you've got the server running and have installed your chosen DB software (MySQL or SQLite most likely) you simply export locally, upload the file via FTP or SSH and then import.

Apologies there isn't any exact code or commands for you here - but this is very much an opinion based question which isn't what StackOverflow is really for - you should maybe try the October CMS Slack channel, or reaching out on the forums.

Comment: Actually i am not sure whether OctoberCMS adding full urls in database tables or not like this http://localhost/october_cms/  .. if yes it will be tough for me you know to change those urls to live one like this http://www.example.com/  ..

Comment: I have just noticed that the table named "system_request_logs" adding urls like this http://localhost/5p_front/install_files/images/leaves.png .. so if i upload and import my whole local database to live server, i will face issue as i need to replace those urls .. what u think

Comment: Ah, that's not an issue. Laravel and October CMS will handle that for you. What you're seeing is an access log - i.e. you have visited those URLs and October CMS is logging them. When you move to production your routes will dynamically update.

Comment: ok so i can expect if i just follow the steps like 1) install fresh october on live server, 2) copying all the plugins and paste to live server, 3) copy whole theme and paste it to live server, 4) just export local database and import it to live server ..  

If i m gonna do this, it will be working fine .. is it so ?

Comment: and also as far as my understanding, i just need to upload or import plugin tables on live server ..